# Pasar parametros a un @GetMapping RestAPI SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

He estado investigando y no he encontrado exactamente lo que busco, además tengo la sensación de que aunque consiguiera lo que busco seguiría sin entender correctamente como funciona el problema que paso a comentar, por eso posteo una pregunta, para ver si alguien puede explicarme un poco.

Lo que pretendo hacer, es desde un front hecho con Vue.js, enviar un usuario, y dos fechas a mi restcontroller, hecho con springboot, y que me devuelva una lista de segmentos asociados a ese usuario entre esas dos fechas.

Ahora bien entiendo que se debería hacer con @getmapping porque es solo de lectura la consulta, pero si no he entendido mal, en lo que he encontrado, @requestbody no se puede usar con @getmapping.

Y realmente tampoco entiendo muy bien todas esas anotaciones de requestbody y demas, si alguien pudiera explicarme se lo agradecería.

Esto es lo que enviaría desde el vue.js

```
methods: {
  get(){
     this.segments = TestRepository.getSegments(this.user,this.startDate,this.endDate);
  },
```

y esta la función en el testRepository

```
response = await HTTP.get(`${resource}`, user, start, end);
```

Y este sería el rest que quiero hacer, y donde encuentro el problema porque no se como recibir esos 3 parametros correctamente.

```
 @GetMapping
 public List<Segment> get( MobileUser u, GregorianCalendar c1, GregorianCalendar c2){
    return testService.getSegments(u, c1, c2);
 }
```

(Aquí si intento accedar a los datos antes de pasar al servicio son nulos, pero en el vue he comprobado que esas variables tienen valor)

Es mi primera pregunta, así que agradezco cualquier crítica constructiva para mejorar.

Comment: Puedes enviar el id del usuario y las fechas como parámetro en la url desde el cliente y recibir en el servicio el identificador de usuario en el formato oportuno (Integer, Long,...) y las fechas como string, añade el código del resource que tienes actualmente para el getSegments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi propuesta es la siguiente:

- En el resource testRepository:

  ```
  async getSegments(idUsuario, fechaIni, fechaFin) {
     return (await HTTP.get(`${resource}/${user}/${start}/${end}`)).data;
  }
  ```
- En el lado servidor (usando @PathVariable) y añadir el "mapeo" correcto:

```
@GetMapping("/{usuID}/{fechaIni}/{fechaFin}")
public List<Segment> get(@PathVariable Long u,@PathVariable String c1, @PathVariable String c2){
   return testService.getSegments(u, c1, c2);
}
```

- Y en el cliente deberías de asegurarte de enviar el id del usuario (considero que se llama id dentro del objeto user) y no el objeto entero, al igual que las fechas en String:

```
methods: {
   get(){
      this.segments = TestRepository.getSegments(
         this.user.id,
         this.startDate,
         this.endDate
      );
 },
```